# Disappearing Build History in Jenkins when Allure plugin is used

Tags: java, jenkins, testing, jenkins-plugins, allure

I'm trying to generate an Allure report for my tests in Jenkins. I installed the Allure plugin, I configured allure-commandline in Global Tool Config and I added post-build action in my Job config. The report is available for a few hours and then disappears. In Job Console Output everything is going well but in the Jenkins Log I have the following error:

```
Failed to save build record
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private java.lang.Object java.lang.ref.Reference.referent accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang.ref" to unnamed module @6f43c82
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary.buildDictionaryEntryForClass(FieldDictionary.java:176)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary.buildMap(FieldDictionary.java:142)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary.fieldsFor(FieldDictionary.java:80)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:167)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:208)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:165)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:59)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:83)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshallField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:285)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:272)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportBuildAction#buildSummary for class ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportBuildAction
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:276)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.visit(RobustReflectionConverter.java:243)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:174)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:228)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:165)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:59)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:44)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:87)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeBareItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:94)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeCompleteItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:81)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.marshal(CollectionConverter.java:75)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:59)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:83)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshallField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:285)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:272)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize hudson.model.Actionable#actions for class hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:276)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.visit(RobustReflectionConverter.java:243)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:174)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:228)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:165)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:68)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:59)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:44)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:83)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:37)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1266)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1255)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:1228)
    at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:213)
Caused: java.io.IOException
    at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:220)
    at hudson.model.Run.save(Run.java:2070)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1956)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:107)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:449)
```

Allure Jenkins Plugin version: 2.30.2
Allure Commandline: 2.19.0
Java version: OpenJDK 18.0.2.1
Jenkins version: 2.361.2

I tried to start Jenkins with the following command but it didn't work:
`Dhudson.remoting.ClassFilter=ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportBuildAction,ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.utils.BuildSummary`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Allure Jenkins Plugin is not yet supports Java 17 and above. Related issue to track progress: https://github.com/jenkinsci/allure-plugin/issues/315